# Can you spot the issue with my indentation?

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python. From my understanding, you need to have a consistent tab or space for your loop blocks. I believe I have that. And yet on line 36 of this program, I keep running into an error. Can anyone point what I am doing wrong here? The error message is telling me I have inconsistent spacing.

```
#High Scores
#Demonstrates list methods

scores=[]
choice = None

while choice!="0":
    print(
    """

    High Scores
    0 - Exit
    1 - Show Scores
    2 - Add a scores
    3 - Delete a Scores
    4 - Sort Scores
    """
    )

    choice = input("Choice: ")
    print()

    #exit
    if choice == "0":
        print("Good-bye.")

    #list high score-table'
    elif choice == "1":
        print("High Scores")
        for score in scores:
        print(score)

    #add a score
    elif choice == "2":
        score = int(input("What score did you get?: "))
        scores.append(score)

    #remove a score
    elif choice == "3":
        score = int(input("Remove which score?: "))
            if score in scores:
                scores.remove(score)
            else:
                print(score,"isn't in the high scores list.")

    #sort scores
    elif choice == "4":
        scores.sort(reverse=True)

    #some unknown choice
    else:
        print("Sorry, but ", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of the error message?

Comment: Your if blocks are all wrong, you should redefine them.

Comment: The block for "4" and the block after it came out misaligned when I pasted it.

Comment: Then you have a tab and spaces on it, that might be the problem

Comment: You should check that your editor doesn't mix tabs and spaces.

Comment: make sure your editor is set to "soft tabs".

Comment: The paste I have here is totally different from the code I am looking at. I have no idea why the pasting, and the code looks differently between my two editors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tip: Use an IDE**

[image: Komodo Python]

The problem is that you have two levels of indentation in this block:

```
elif choice == "2":
            score = int(input("What score did you get?: "))
    scores.append(score)
```

Technically, it doesn't matter if you use tabs or spaces, and how many you use, as long as you're consistent. Of course there is a strong preference for four spaces, per the [Python style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Apparently Google uses two spaces!

So you have to fix this code. This means:

```
elif choice == "2":
    score = int(input("What score did you get?: "))
    scores.append(score)
```

**An IDE will spot many indentation errors**

As you can see from the screenshot, an IDE will flag problem lines... and save you lots of time. This particular screenshot is from Komodo IDE, but most IDEs that support Python syntax should give you something similar.

Comment: FYI, added screenshot of IDE flagging the problem lines. :)

Comment: I am using notepad++ and Idle 3. The weird thing is that the indents are different between them even though tab is set to 4 spaces in both.

Comment: Often, when you inherit a file, you have to tell the editor or IDE to specifically apply certain settings to that file. And yeah, some are better than others. :) ActiveState is very active in the Python field, you might want to tryout one of their freebies.

Comment: The error it is giving me is on line 29. Is it running on your side?

Comment: Once you fix that one, other problems appear: an `else` on line 43, `elif` on 47, else` on 50... And yes, it's running now. :)

Comment: It runs for me with [this exact indentation](http://ideone.com/LHTBnD) (not on that site, but on my Python)

Comment: @munchschair don't use tab but only spaces.

Answer (score 4):

## Python indentation 101

1. You should use either spaces *or* tabs. Choose what you like in the beginning, and **stick with it**

   1. In case you're using spaces, choose how many, and **stick with it** (most people use 4 spaces in the Python community)
2. Configure your editor to use the indentation scheme you chose. Tell it to convert tabs to *n* spaces if needed, etc. This will avoid you mixing indentation conventions and having to deal with this stuff. For instance, vim allows you to set this kind of stuff in a shebang-like comment at the beginning of your files.
3. Each and every time you enter a block (that is generally a statement ending with `:`), you stack one indent. You may *not* add indent at other places.
4. Each and every time you close a block, unstack an indent.
5. You should only stack indent one *unit* at a time
6. That's pretty much it.

## Your code

Let's review your code. Everything's fine until you get to line 35.

```
34.    elif choice == "2":
35.                score = int(input("What score did you get?: "))
36.        scores.append(score)
```

Asking user input should be done when choice is `"2"`. You've got one indent at line 34, four at line 35, and two at line 36. You should have `1-2-2`.

```
34.    elif choice == "2":
35.        score = int(input("What score did you get?: "))
36.        scores.append(score)
```

Same goes for lines 42 and 44:

```
38.    #remove a score
39.    elif choice == "3":
40.        score = int(input("Remove which score?: "))
41.                if score in scores:
42.                        scores.remove(score)
43.                else:
44.                        print(score,"isn't in the high scores list.")
```

Instead of `1-1-2-4-6-4-6`, you need `1-1-2-2-3-2-3`:

```
38.    #remove a score
39.    elif choice == "3":
40.        score = int(input("Remove which score?: "))
41.        if score in scores:
42.            scores.remove(score)
43.        else:
44.            print(score,"isn't in the high scores list.")
```

Again, for lines 48 and 52:

```
46.        #sort scores
47.        elif choice == "4":
48.                scores.sort(reverse=True)
49.
50.        #some unknown choice
51.        else:
52.                print("Sorry, but ", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")
```

You put `2-2-4-2-2-2-4`, while the `if` block you continue with an `elif` started at indent `1`. You need `1-1-2-1-1-1-2`:

```
46.    #sort scores
47.    elif choice == "4":
48.        scores.sort(reverse=True)
49.
50.    #some unknown choice
51.    else:
52.        print("Sorry, but ", choice, "isn't a valid choice.")
```

---

**Edit after OP's [second revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/24425845/2)** (thanks to @[elParaguayo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3087339/elparaguayo)):

At line 31, the body of the `for` loop is empty:

```
27.    #list high score-table'
28.    elif choice == "1":
29.        print("High Scores")
30.        for score in scores:
31.        print(score)
```

I read `1-1-2-2-2` where it should be `1-1-2-2-3` (as in initial version):

```
27.    #list high score-table'
28.    elif choice == "1":
29.        print("High Scores")
30.        for score in scores:
31.            print(score)
```

There's no more problem at line 35.

Block 38-44 became `1-1-2-3-4-3-4`, but the corerction still applies.

Removed problems on block `46-52`.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to the other answers. This looks wrong too:

```
#list high score-table'
elif choice == "1":
    print("High Scores")
    for score in scores:
    print(score)
```

should be

```
#list high score-table'
elif choice == "1":
    print("High Scores")
    for score in scores:
        print(score)
```

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint indentation errors when the indents on the question change continuously. When I copy/pasted the OP's code, the `print`was correctly aligned.

Comment: Yes. That would make it difficult. I've just seen this post and that's how it was showing for me. Happy for you to add this to your answer and I'll remove this one.